# Edge Crashing with HTML5 storage exceeded

Tags: azure, microsoft-edge, html5

I have this problem when I try to access Azure using Edge:

This is what's showing in the URL
"https://portal.azure.com/Error/UE_Html5StorageExceeded?shown=true" 
[image: This is what the Browser was showing]

I'm running Windows 10 Pro, build 15063.483

I've had this problem for some time, I'm sure there's a simple answer, but I can't find it. I've got to say I've found Edge to be running fairly rough and have wondered if it needs some sort of repair?
**How can i get Edge to work properly?**

Comment: Can you supply some error code or more deails of your trouble?:- on behalf of Wayne Yang - who will poss remove his answer

Comment: Hi mic84, it's not giving me any other details. Funny thing is that since you edited the question, (that url was the only error message I really had, so you've obscured it by substituting the 'Work or school, or personal Microsoft account' as the link text) I can click on the URL and it works? It just gets weirder. I figured it was some sort of known problem, but no-one seems to have encountered it. If I can get it again I'll get a picture of the screen, It's all blue and says something like 'Oops...' I figured it was something to do with local storage, read the URL

Comment: There we go it worked like magic, closed Edge and It's broken again. I've restored what the URL was showing, which make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not feel like wiping out all cookies and website data for all sites so being in the Azure sign in page, I hit F12 in MS Edge to open "Developer Tools", then went to "Storage" tab and proceeded to select each an every one of the data items hanging off the navigation tree on the left and deleted all data items showing for each of these in rows on the panel on the left (clicked top one to select and repeatedly hit "Delete" key 'til none left). This did the trick for me and sharing in the hope that it will help others as well. :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to your error information, I copied the URL, and paste in my edge, then I opened the Azure portal successfully. However, I tried to change the URL to be this: https://portal.azure.com/Error/UE_Html5StorageExceeded?shown=false . Then I  couldn’t open this link, and I got the same picture as you posted.

This issue may caused by  Edge Storage , I suggest you clear Edge storage and try to restart Edge and put the correct URL ,just like : [portal.azure.com](http://portal.azure.com)

and try again.

How to clear Edge storage Area:   Edge>Settings>Clear Browsing data>Choose what to clear>Choose Cookies and saved website data> Clear
Even you can clear more data and try again.

Comment: Thanks I did a big clean out and it fixed it, it took 2 attempts, it failed the first time. I had tried before and it it failed, it just needed the retry until it worked.